# Darkflow can't find the cfg and weights file

Tags: python, tensorflow, canopy, darkflow

I'm trying to setup YOLO in enthought canopy environment on a windows machine. Since both tensorflow and darkflow don't seem to be available on package manager, I  installed them via pip

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and after downloading the darkflow directory from github and navigating to it from canopy command prompt

```
pip install .
```

and then

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

for the setting up the the cython_utils. Now, the command line demo seems to work fine

```
python flow --model cfg/yolo.cfg --load bin/yolo.weights --demo videofile.mp4 --saveVideo
```

but when I try to run the following in my canopy editor:

```
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
option = {'model': 'cfg/yolo.cfg', 'load': 'bin/yolo.weights', 'threshold': 0.3}
tfnet = TFNet(option)
```

It throws me this error:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\umair\appdata\local\temp\tmp9n4e92.py in <module>()
      4 option = {'model': 'cfg/yolo.cfg', 'load': 'bin/yolo.weights', 'threshold': 0.3}
      5 
----> 6 tfnet = TFNet(option)

C:\Users\umair\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\darkflow\net\build.py in __init__(self, FLAGS, darknet)
     56 
     57                 if darknet is None:
---> 58                         darknet = Darknet(FLAGS)
     59                         self.ntrain = len(darknet.layers)
     60 
C:\Users\umair\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\darkflow\dark\darknet.py in __init__(self, FLAGS)
     11 
     12     def __init__(self, FLAGS):
---> 13         self.get_weight_src(FLAGS)
     14         self.modify = False
     15 
C:\Users\umair\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\darkflow\dark\darknet.py in get_weight_src(self, FLAGS)
     45         else:
     46             assert os.path.isfile(FLAGS.load), \
---> 47             '{} not found'.format(FLAGS.load)
     48             self.src_bin = FLAGS.load
     49             name = loader.model_name(FLAGS.load)
AssertionError: bin/yolo.weights not found
```

I tried copying the bin and cfg folder from my original directory where I extracted darkflow to site-packages/darkflow folder:

```
C:\Users\umair\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\Lib\site-packages\darkflow
```

but that doesn't seem to work either. Ironically, that works perfectly fine in the python console through canopy command prompt
[image: canopy command prompt]

So what's wrong with all this basically? Have I made some mistake in package installation? Missed adding paths somewhere? or I'm placing the bin and cfg folder at incorrect location?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe the code is assuming that it is running in the same directory as your script. This cannot be assumed. You can either change the working directory at the ipython prompt in Canopy editor, or you can configure Canopy to do this for you automatically. See the Canopy docs: https://docs.enthought.com/canopy/2.1/quick-start/code_editor.html#change-directory